# Could one WebRtcConnection handle both screen sharing and camera video?

Tags: webrtc

I am trying to create a peer to peer meeting basing on WebRtc, I am able to see him on his camera, or watch his shared screen, but may I watch his screen and meanwhile watching him on his camera?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this demo:** https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/demos/screen-and-video-from-single-peer.html

For offerer; it attaches two unique `MediaStream` objects:

1. Audio+Video
2. Screen

Remember, **Firefox doesn't support** this feature, yet!